# What plugin should I use for booking events and receiving payments?

Tags: plugins, plugin-recommendation, events

What plugin would you recommend for booking events and receiving payments. I have approx 70 classes per year in a swim club that people can sign up for.

Comment: @Morten - Can you give us a little more information?  How do you want events listed?  How do you want people to book the events?  What provider do you want to receive payments through?

Answer (score 1):

I've used [EventBrite](http://www.eventbrite.com/) as a service for scheduling and ticketing events in the past.  It's low-cost and integrates with both PayPal and Google Checkout for receiving payments.  Using an external provider also takes the stress and accountability off my shoulders when it comes to validating signups and keeping track of an attendee list.

There's also [a WordPress plug-in to integrate with EventBrite](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/eventbrite-for-the-events-calendar/).  It requires a particular event calendar (which I can't seem to find at the moment) but it should give you a good start for building an integration between your site and EventBrite.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm was hoping to have a WordPress Native solution (instead of third party) - but I know (and have used EventBrite), so that would be a good third party solution, if something doesn't "come up" .. Thanks again

Comment: A WordPress "native" solution would be to use any available WP shopping cart plug-in and sell "tickets" as a product.  You aren't shipping anything, just recording contact information and purchases.

Comment: yes- could try e-commerce (getshopped) or shopp or something like that....thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest looking into this one:

http://wpdevelop.com/wp-plugins/booking-calendar/